# Converting DNF to CNF

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, conjunctive-normal-form, disjunctive-normal-form

I am confused on how to convert DNF to CNF. On the answer sheet that my teacher gave me, she just converted it right away with no explanation. Any help would be great.

Myy teacher converted $F: (A \wedge \neg B) \vee (B \wedge D)$ to CNF form of $(A \vee B) \wedge (\neg B \vee D)$. How does that go? Is there a way of converting it without drawing the truth tables?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

De Morgan's Law states $ \neg(a + b) \equiv \neg a\neg b $ and $\neg(ab) \equiv \neg a + \neg b$.
$$\begin{equation} \begin{aligned}A\neg B + BD \equiv & \neg(\neg(A\neg B)\neg(BD)) \text{ De Morgan's outside} \\ \equiv & \neg((\neg A + B)(\neg B + \neg D)) \text{ De Morgan's inside} \\ \equiv & \neg(\neg A \neg B + \neg A \neg D + B \neg D) \text{ Distributivity} \\ \equiv & \neg(\neg A \neg B + \neg A \neg D (\neg B + B) + B \neg D) \text{ Complementation} \\ \equiv & \neg(\neg A \neg B + \neg A \neg D \neg B + \neg A \neg D B + B \neg D) \text{ Distributivity} \\ \equiv & \neg(\neg A \neg B(1 + \neg D) + B \neg D (1 + \neg A)) \text{ Distributivity} \\ \equiv & \neg(\neg A \neg B + B \neg D) \text{ Annihilator} \\ \equiv & (A + B)(\neg B + D) \text{ De Morgan's outside}\end{aligned}\end{equation} $$

You might also want to look into [K-maps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map).

Comment: Thank you! It's very clear although, I'm not sure on why do you do the complementation on the -A-D? Is there any particular reason? Also the expression is actually derived from K-maps, I'm just not sure how to get the CNF expression out of K-maps

Comment: @Stud Which line?

Comment: ¬(¬A¬B+¬A¬D(¬B+B)+B¬D) Complementation line. I understand you can multiply by -B+B since it equals 1 and it doesn't change everything. I'm just not sure why do you choose to complement the B+-B with the -A-D, why not the -A-B or B-D? Perhaps using a different set of complementation? such as A-A or D-D?

Comment: I noticed that the two other terms contained $B$ and $\neg B$ which told me that the middle term could be eliminated due to the way the terms were matched. If I'm going to be honest, it was mainly intuition and reasoning logically. It's a trick that you can use sometimes when you're not sure how to eliminate terms.

Comment: Ahhhh I don't quite see that the first place. Thanks for pointing it out, also thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a simpler way than the accepted answer:

$$\begin{equation} \begin{aligned}A\neg B \vee BD 
\equiv & (A \vee B)(A \vee D)(\neg B \vee B)(\neg B \vee D) \text{ Distributivity} \\ 
\equiv & (A \vee B)(A \vee D) 1 (\neg B \vee D) \text{ Tertium non datur} \\ 
\equiv & (A \vee B)(A \vee D)(\neg B \vee D) \text{ Neutral element of $\wedge$} \\ 
\equiv & (A \vee B)(\neg B \vee D) \text{ middle term is redundant*}
\end{aligned}\end{equation} $$

*  $A\vee D$ is only false if both A and D are false but then the whole term is false anyway because it reduces to $(B)(A \vee D)(\neg B)$.